# Grafana multi-line chart from Postgres

Tags: grafana

I want to display a multi-line chart where each line it's the value of a column.
For example, "status" has several values: 200, 404, 500 etc.. and I want to see a line for each. On X-axis I have to see how many records had the status=200 and so on..

I've tried with this

```
SELECT
  created_at AS "time",
  status,
  count(*) 
FROM api_logs
group BY time, status
```

but it's showing

[image]

instead I would something like

[image]

UPDATED:
I tried with this query

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(created_at, '5m'),
  status AS "metric",
  count(*) AS "count"
FROM api_logs
WHERE $__timeFilter(created_at)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

ORDER BY 1

but I got this chart

[image]

and this is the table output

[image]

I would see a line for each status. Where Y is the count of event for that status. Basically If I see a spike for a line (errors 500) I have to worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL query with 5min time aggregation with PostgreSQL macros for Grafana 8.2:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(created_at, '5m'),
  status AS "metric",
  count(*) AS "count"
FROM api_logs
WHERE $__timeFilter(created_at)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

`created_at` column is `timestamptz` type.

Comment: I've tried but still not getting the desired output. I've updated the question with details.

Comment: @sparkle cast status as text in that query, becaue you have it as numeric type now, e.g. `status::text AS "metric",`. You should to also mention used Grafana version and panel type first in your question.

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same issue as well, using Grafana 10 though.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not solve it for me.
I'm using Grafana 10 and what solved is was using the multi-frame time series transformation:
[image]

[Source](https://community.grafana.com/t/grouping-is-not-working-as-expected-in-a-time-series-panel/80782/4)